Combine pandas columns and add parentheses around each item
I have the following table:



Name
Subjects
Grades




George
[Math, Science, History]
[90,82,93]


Kathy
[English, Science, History, Math]
[92,85,96,99]



I want to get this table:



Name
Subjects
Grades
Results




George
[Math, Science, History]
[90,82,93]
[Math (90 grade), Science (82 grade), History (93 grade)]


Kathy
[English, Science, History, Math]
[92,85,96,99]
[English (92 grade), Science (85 grade), History (96 grade), Math (99 grade)]



I am unfamiliar how to do this within a dataframe column. I know for a list you would do something like this:
l1 = ['Math', 'Science', 'History']
l2 = [90, 82, 93]
l3 = [f'({x} grade)' for x in l2]
print('[' + ', '.join(f"{x} {y}" for x, y in zip(l1, l3)) + ']')
[Math (90 grade), Science (82 grade), History (93 grade)]




You need to use a loop/list comprehension as well with pandas. The most efficient should be:
df['Results'] = [[f'{s} ({g} grade)' for s,g in zip(*x)]
                 for x in zip(df['Subjects'], df['Grades'])]

A less efficient, but more generic method with explode and apply:
text = '{Subjects} ({Grades} grade)'

df['Results'] = (df.explode(['Subjects', 'Grades'])
                   .apply(lambda x: text.format(**dict(x)), axis=1)
                   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
                )

Output:
      Name                           Subjects            Grades                                                                        Results
0  George            [Math, Science, History]      [90, 82, 93]                      [Math (90 grade), Science (82 grade), History (93 grade)]
1   Kathy   [English, Science, History, Math]  [92, 85, 96, 99]  [English (92 grade), Science (85 grade), History (96 grade), Math (99 grade)]

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['George', 'Kathy'],
                   'Subjects': [['Math', 'Science', 'History'],
                                ['English', 'Science', 'History', 'Math']],
                   'Grades': [[90,82,93], [92,85,96,99]]})


Assuming the data is not really big and is represented as  lists, I'd go this way:
columns = ['Subjects', 'Grades']
pattern = '{0} ({1} grade)'.format

df['Results'] = df[columns].agg(lambda rec: [pattern(*data) for data in zip(*rec)], axis=1)

This gives you a freedom to change the data to be aggregated as well as the pattern to represent them.
See also:
   Format String Syntax
   pandas.DataFrame.agg
